# Can't login to the backend of a fresh TYPO3 install

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

**Here is what I did:**

1. Downloaded zip TYPO3 11.3.0 from https://get.typo3.org/version/11
2. Unzip into `/subfolder`
3. `touch FIRST_INSTALL`
4. Followed instructions of the setup wizard with new database
5. Try to login via `/subfolder/typo3/` and enter credentials
6. `/subfolder/typo3/login?loginProvider=...` leads to a 404

**What I already checked:**

- `typo3temp/var/log/typo3_[...].log` is empty
- MAMP logs don't show anything suspicious
- Install Tool Environment Status shows a weird error:
  `http://localhost:8888/subfolder/typo3temp/assets/e35bd633.tmp/e77fab4e.php.wrong: unexpected content PHP content`
- Install Tool Directory Status is all green
- Original `.htaccess` file exists
- Created `typo3conf/sites/mysite/config.yaml` by copying from an existing (working) project, TYPO3 10

Of course, before I created the site configuration YAML, `/subfolder/typo3/login?loginProvider=...` was leading to a "no site config" error.
Now, it feels like there is a problem with the `.htaccess`, but I can't pinpoint where.

Running Apache / PHP 7.4.12

Comment: Still not fixed - ended up installing TYPO3 10.4.17 the same way and it worked

Comment: does it maybe have something to do that itÄs inside the "subfolder" ? usualy you have /typo3 at the base. Maybe set the sw-cms-block-registration-request on the htacces to /subfolder

Comment: There is a similar bug with a fix: 

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/94054

Comment: TYPO3 always had issues with subfolder installations, best and always working in this case is using the subdomains instead. Keep this as a rule of the thumb.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure to use the proper .htaccess configuration for CMS 11, so you can't just reuse the one provided with CMS 10.

Have a look at this documentation of the related breaking change in TYPO3 CMS 11
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.0/Breaking-93048-BackendURLRewrites.html